# xgboost выбор ошибки при поиске экстремальных значений

Tags: машинное-обучение, xgboost

Тренирую регрессию `xgboost` c `objective = 'reg:squarederror`.

Результаты имеют нормальное распределение от -10 до +10. Для меня важна ошибка `reg:squarederror` в предсказаний положительных значений свыше 7. Их 10% от всего датасета. Ошибка предсказания целей от -10 до 7  значения не имеет.

Какие есть подходы к решению такой задачи:

- задать веса наблюдений через `sample_weight`?
- использовать другой `objective`, какой?
- `oversampling` всего что выше 7?

Пример.

- Предсказали 10 реально -10 или (-10/10). самая большая ошибка
- Предсказали 10 реально 7. небольшая ошибка
- Предсказали 10 реально 0. большая ошибка
- Предсказали -10 реально (от -10 до 6). ошибка не интересна

Comment: Ну, напишите и используйте свою функцию вычисления ошибок, если не путаю, большинство моделей позволяют передать параметром свою функцию ошибок. Хотя погодите. Если таргет в диапазоне от -10 до 7 будет означать нулевую ошибку, то модели будет выгодно предсказывать числа именно в этом диапазоне и других она вообще не будет предсказывать. Думаю, вам надо пояснить свой вопрос какими-то примерами, в данной формулировке что-то не так.

Comment: @CrazyElf , вопрос отредактировала, дополнила примером.

Comment: А, всё, я немного протупил. Почитайте пару ссылок для начала: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683944/creating-a-custom-objective-function-in-for-xgboost-xgbregressor Я так сходу не скажу, как именно надо будет модифицировать кастомную функцию в вашем случае, нужно будет думать, но куда копать вроде понятно должно быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf да,рассматривала, как один из вариантов. Как думаете, переписать гессиан и градиент для 'reg:squarederror' добавив в их функции обнуление при целях от -10 до 6, логично? а для 7-10 оставить стандартный расчет 'reg:squarederror'. И не будет ли тот же эффект, если использовать стандартную метрику и дать всем целям  от -10 до 6 веса 'sample_weight':0, а остальным 1?

Comment: Возможно, вы правы, я с `sample_weight` сам не экспериментировал, возможно это и вариант, причём самый простой. Надо попробовать и посмотреть. Но чтобы оценить результат работы модели всё-равно ведь придётся как-то скор считать. Как именно модифицировать гессиан и градиент не могу сказать, надо думать, пробовать. Если б это просто метрика качества была, то понятно там занулять надо, а с этими я не знаю.

Comment: Наверное и правда можно спокойно занулять - если данная цель неважна, то и направления движения нет никакого, нулевой вектор скорости.